# jQuery Twitter hack failing in TamperMonkey but not in the console

Tags: jquery, twitter, tampermonkey

Twitter has added "Don't miss..." footer to its web interface, and I want to remove it.  This Tampermonkey (v4.10.6105 on Firefox 73.0.1) script doesn't work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Clean up twitter argle bargle
// @include     https://twitter.com/*
// @require     http://ajaxgoogleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$('.r-zchlnj').remove();
```

where `r-zchlnj` is one of the classes in the div surrounding the footer.  If I go into the console, I get (approximately, there's some decorations that aren't cutting and pasting)

```
>>$('.r-zchlnj')
<div class="r-1d2f490 r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af r-184en5c" style="">
>>$('.r-zchlnj').remove()
undefined
>>
```

and the footer is gone.  Adding one of

```
@grant unsafeWindow
```

as suggested below or

```
@grant none
```

because running the script unsandboxed directly on the page itself sounds like it might work or

```
@grant window.focus
```

because maybe window focus comes after the footer placement (I don't understand browser window focus) to the script doesn't remove the footer.

Although the script could be bad, my guess is the script's being run before some Javascript grafts the footer into the DOM.  Is there a more informed explanation, and, more importantly, technique for removing the footer?

Comment: https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#_grant you may have to grant unsafeWindow

Comment: `my guess is the script's being run before some Javascript grafts the footer into the DOM` this is my guess too. The quick and dirty fix would be to use a timeout. The better fix would be to use a MutationObserver

Comment: Also note that jQuery 1.3.2 is 11 years out of date. I'd suggest using a newer version

Comment: The script runs before twitter creates those elements. Use [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Comment: There's no need to wait though if hiding via CSS suits you: simply add a `<style>` element with `.r-zchlnj { display: none !important }` inside

Comment: _There's no need to wait though if hiding via CSS suits you_  It does (I should have thought of that), but to make sure I understand:  I still need a delay framework in place (like ```MutationObserver``` or ```waitForKeyElements```) to apply the changes after the elements hit the dom, correct?

Comment: It seems the problem has solved itself: Twitter is no longer sending out the footer (this is, of course, naive when looking at something driven by megabytes of JavaScript, but I'll take it for now).